# Xcode 7 no matching profile found and no general tab

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have a project in Xcode 7 that had to update provisioning profiles. I created both new certificates and provisioning profiles on the developer site, and then downloaded them and double clicked them to install them. But when I try to build the project I get the "No matching provisioning profiles found" error.

I tried to use Xcode to fix the issue but it was not successful. I also tried Xcode ->  preferences -> acount -> view details -> download all / clean / build. But that did not help. I noticed that other projects have a "general" tab where I can select team, but in this project I do not.

What can I do to fix this, any suggestion greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you are selecting PROJECT instead of TARGETS.

Comment: I select "project navigator" and select the project, but I only se the "info" tab and the "build settings" tab. Not the "general", "capabilities" and so on..... Shouldnt the "general" tab be where I look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select TARGETS to get that General Tab.

[image: Image with Project Selected]
[image: Image with Target Selected]

Comment: Ahh, I must have hide that view by accident... I was able to find the general tab by your help and also solve the issue. Thanks for all help!

Comment: Great that it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks @AriBlack for this complement, I am glad that it helped you :)